# get width/height of <img> with js. No calculated styles

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to get the width and height of an image HTML element. I don't want any default styles, which got applied by the browser or calculated styles.

Here are some examples:

```
<img src="" alt="" width="200px" height="100px" />
```

Result: w=200, h=200

```
<img src="" alt="" height="100px" style="width: 150px;"/>
```

Result: w=150, h=200

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 50px;>
    <img src="" alt="" style="width: 150px;"/>
</div>
```

Result: w=150 h=Null

So, i want to get the width/height if it is set via inline css or the old tag. External is not needed. If the width isn't set specifically, i want to get null.

How can i do that? I've tried:

```
$(this).height;
$(this).css('height');
```

Didn't work. The only thing i can think about is getting the style string with:

```
$(this).find('style');
```

and apply an regex on it. For the width and height tag, it should be possible to use:

```
$(this).attr('width');
```

Didn't test that, since it it useless if i don't have the style="" one as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)?

Comment: Yes, i wrote it wrong. Sry. .width will just output the code, no width ;) But thanks

Answer (score 0):

not sure but try this:

`$(this).height();`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like .height() and .width() don't work fully:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tszjs/12/

The example shows that if inline styling is present for either width or height then the old height="x" and width="y" attributes will be ignored.

I would suggest that in your code you check for the old attributes to see if they exist and if they do combine them with the inline style override. For example:

```
<img id="test2" src="" alt="" height="100px" style="width: 150px;" />
<script>
var test2= $("#test2");
var oldHeight=test2.attr("height");
var oldWidth=test2.attr("width");
var myHeight,myWidth;

if(oldHeight!=undefined) { myHeight=oldHeight; } else { myHeight=test2.height();} 
if(oldWidth!=undefined) { myWidth=oldWidth; } else { myWidth=test2.width();} 

document.write("CORRECT ---- Height: " +  myHeight + "px - Width: " +  myWidth + "px<br />");
</script>
```

​

Comment: It behvaes really strange. Also, your example doesn't seem to work properly. Result 2 got an height. I also think each browser will handle this differently. I'm probably just going to allow the attributes. Thanks